# The same textfield with other size in iOS 5.1 and 6.0

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, ios6, ios5.1, uifont

i've got one `UITextfield`:

```
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 33)];
    [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Regular" size:14]] ;
    [textField setDelegate:self];
```

Below you can see `textfield` on `iOS 6.0` and `iOS 5.1`.
[image]

[image]

Why on 5.1 text it's bigger? In `setFont` size is `14`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand You make screenshot from simulators. If It's true text on 5.1 will be always bigger then on 6.0, because resolution of screens different between iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 but the size of the "windows" for simulator  iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 are the same.

Comment: but width on screen is the same. it's not possible to change size of text. i don't understand this :/

Comment: if you compare text on real iPhone 4 and iPhone, it will be the same size, because real size of screen different but for simulators text will be visually different, because for simulator size of screen are the same